# executing groups of ajax requests one after another

Tags: ajax

I have 3 arrays with 10 urls each.

What i want is:

First all the ajax requests of urls in the first array get executed.

Then the ajax requests of second array urls get executed

and in the last the third array requests ursl get executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use promises (ES6) to queue your requests and continue once the queue is cleared.

```
var array1 = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];
var array2 = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4'];
var array3 = ['url1', 'url2'];

function createPromiseArray(list){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      var queue = [];
      for(var i=0; list.length > i; i++){
          queue.push(doRequest(list[i]));
      }
      Promise.all(queue).then(function(){
          resolve();
      });
    }
}

function doRequest(url){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        // do ajax request
        if (!error) {
            resolve(data);
        }else{
            reject(data);
        }
    }
}

createPromiseArray(array1)
   .then(function(){
       createPromiseArray(array2);
   })
   .then(function(){
       createPromiseArray(array3);
   })
   .then(function(){
       console.log('all done');
   })
```

more info on promises can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

You may also need to use a polyfill for older browsers which you can find here https://www.promisejs.org/

Comment: it woked to some extent. It says  "error is not defined"

Comment: that's just an example which should come from your ajax call. When your ajax call returns an error add something like `var error = data.error;` That will define the error variable. Depending whether it's true or false will determine the promise resolving or being rejected.

Comment: i didn't understand reject and resolve and the parameters data and error.

Comment: I understood the concept of promises. Some changes i have to do, which made the code worked.